# Page Object Patern in Java Selenium - update of elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I use Page Object Pattern in Java Selenium and I've got problem with updating element after click action.
There is a list of X elements on page and button that enables to scroll them (after clicking on button, new elements are displayed on the list, old ones disappear)

There are two classes:

```
public abstract class WebPage {

protected WebDriver driver;

WebPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30)), this);
}
```

and

```
public class ChildClass extends WebPage{

@FindBy(selector)
List<WebElement> elements;

By nextButton = By.id(xxx);

   ChildClass(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

public void iterateAllElements(){
for (WebElement element: elements){
 //some action 
}
if(buttonIsEnabled())
clickOnButton();
iterateAllElements();

}
}
```

Please tell me why object "elements" is not initialized with new values after invoking clickOnButton(); function? I cannot get elements that are displayed on 2nd, 3rd page ect
There are still elements from 1st view on the list. It works fine in debug mode, but problem occurs when I want to run it.

Comment: if "some action" causes the DOM to update, you'll need to re-get the list of elements.

Comment: shouldn't "elements" object be re-intitilized automatically with new values, after DOM update if we use Page Object Pattern?

Comment: Not familiar with the framework you're using, but doesn't look like it.  Not sure how it would know that an update had been made.  Unless it uses a webdriver event listener?  Even then you'd need some way to track the element actions and re-iterate that loop.